# How to get attributes of SecKeychainRef?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, keychain

How do I retrieve the attributes of a `SecKeychainRef` object?

Thanks

Comment: Which attributes are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I want to get a `SecKeychainItemRef` from a `SecKeycainRef` but `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes` is deprecated in `10.7` and above

Comment: So you want to find passwords stored in a keychain, not information about the keychain itself?

Comment: Correct. Is there a method to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a more general answer to the question of a replacement for the deprecated `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes` (which is the search that lead me to this page), `SecItemCopyMatching` is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation above, sounds like you're looking for `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword()` or `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword()`. For more information on using the keychain in Mac OS X, including replacements for recently-deprecated APIs, you should read the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/)